# pandas dataframe can not be displayed and the system message is on the output

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make pandas dataframe output but dataframe(df9 on the attached example)  can not be displayed and the system message is on the output, which I want to delete.

Please advise

[image: n]

Comment: Have you tried `print(df9)` ?

Comment: thanks
print(df9) works but there is no layout.
`
              pips
eaname            
Kiwami        12.0
BlackPanther -38.3
`

Comment: what do you mean by no layout? Upload a screenshot on imgur.com

Comment: Hello!

I upload screen shot on Jupyter notebook.
https://adobe.ly/2t9Xv75

Thanks for your advise